# Application level error handling on API response

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api, sitecore

I'm working on a big Sitecore project where I'm using MVC and JQuery.

Sometimes, there is no response from server when an API is called, so user gets stuck with the spinning wheel.

Is there any optimum way for me to handle this at the application-level and redirect user to FAIL page?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you'll want to handle the error in the JavaScript method that is making the AJAX request.  jQuery.ajax has the **error** callback function where you can execute your own JavaScript code and redirect the user to a friendly error page.  Another option would be to display a friendly error message on the page where the data that should've been returned by the API call would have displayed.

Let's say you have a block of HTML where the data returned by the api will be inserted:

```
<div class="api-data">

</div>
```

The following JavaScript code would make an AJAX call to the API method and upon a successful response, it would append the response from the API method to the DIV above.  On an error, it would redirect the user to a friendly error page:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'example.com',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(dataReturnedByApi) {
            $('.api-data').html(dataReturnedByApi);
        },
        error: function() {
            window.location = '/friendly-error-page';
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: no! can't change all scripts in all pages of project.